Why where clause is not executing in SQL CTE(Common Table Expression) but works with Join?
While executing SQL query, in Common Table Expression is where clause different from  join clause?
I have created Database Schema called techTFQ and inside schema created  table  employee  as table name.   Employee  table further categorised into three columns named as emp_id, emp_name, salary
After inserting data into the table it looks like as depicted in figure below:
From this table I wanted to fetch the data of employees who earn more than average salary of all employees
My query using a Common Table Expression for this question is:
with average_salary as (
select avg(salary) from employee
)
select *
from employee 
where salary > average_salary;

But this query generates an error:

15:04:37  with average_Salary as ( select avg(salary) from employee ) select *  from employee where salary > average_salary   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'average_salary' in 'where clause' 0.00072 sec

But when I use JOIN clause with the following SQL query:
with average_salary_cte as   (
select avg(salary) as average_salary
from employee
)
select *
from employee e 
join average_salary_cte  a
on e.salary > a.average_salary;

Successfully executed the Query & gives output as i needed :
Now, the question is why I'm not able to execute the code with first SQL query i.e
with average_salary as (
select avg(salary) from employee
)
select *
from employee 
where salary > average_salary;



tag only a single RDBMS 2) don't use images, use table markdown


average_salary in your first example is a table, you're trying to use it as a scalar value. you could define it as a variable instead of a cte and select into it if that's all you're wanting.

I've removed the conflicting tags. Please tag a single rdbms

You also don't alias your column in your CTE average_salary, so that will likely cause a syntax error.

No need for a CTE here, just remove it and use a standard sub query. CTE's are better for complex queries, not for a trivial average.

A CTE is an ad-hoc view and creates a result table. You can join a table, but you cannot compare a table with a single value.
Let's use better alias names to show what is happening:
with as my_aggregation_result_table as
(
  select avg(salary) as average_salary
  from employee
)
select *
from employee 
where salary > my_aggregation_result_table;

You are comparing employee.salary with a complete table, which is syntactically forbidden. Instead select the value you want to compare from the one-column-one-row table:
with as my_aggregation_result_table as
(
  select avg(salary) as average_salary
  from employee
)
select *
from employee 
where salary > (select average_salary from my_aggregation_result_table);

